# Pandas Cumsum skip rows

Tags: python, pandas, cumsum

I have a dataframe like the following.

```
idx vals
0   10
1   21
2   12
3   33
4   14
5   55
6   16
7   77
```

I would like to perform a `cumsum` (and avoid a `for`) but only considering rows with the same `idx` `mod 2`. For instance, for row 3 I would like to obtain `21+33=54`, while for row 4, `10+12+14 = 36`.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just need `groupby` here

```
df.vals.groupby(df.idx%2).cumsum()
Out[75]: 
0     10
1     21
2     22
3     54
4     36
5    109
6     52
7    186
Name: vals, dtype: int64
```